# Gstreamer apply audio delay to live stream

Tags: audio, stream, gstreamer, delay, rtmp

I would like to add an audio delay (up to 10/15 seconds) in a live stream with gstreamer rtmpsink
this is my line

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vvv flvmux streamable=true name=mux ! rtmpsink location="rtmp://localhost/live" \
 souphttpsrc location="http://<url video h264>" ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. \
 souphttpsrc location="https://<url audio aac>" ! icydemux ! aacparse ! queue ! mux.
```

acting directly on the line I tried to add "queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 min-threshold-time=15000000000" after accparse but the entire stream is blocked in this way

acting in c i tried to modify the pts timestamp on the aacparse pad's buffer, but i can change with any value and there is no effect

```
gst_pad_add_probe(line->aacparse_srcpad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER, cb_have_data_audio, NULL, NULL);

..

static GstPadProbeReturn
cb_have_data_audio (GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info, gpointer user_data)
{
  GstMapInfo map;
  GstBuffer *buffer;

  buffer = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER (info);
  buffer = gst_buffer_make_writable (buffer);
  
  if (buffer == NULL)
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
    
  GstClockTime pts = GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer);
  GST_BUFFER_PTS(buffer) = pts + 100000000000;

  GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_DATA (info) = buffer;

  return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}
```

I tried also to use gst_pad_set_offset(), but again no effect

```
gst_pad_set_offset(line->aacparse_srcpad, 1000000000);
```

even playing with the flvmux pads and setting "streamable=false" there is no effect, what should be the right approach to add delay only to the audio?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include<stdio.h>
static GMainLoop *loop;
static gint counter;
static GstBus *bus;
static gboolean prerolled = FALSE;
static GstPad *sinkpad,*ident_sink;
static GstClockTime ptimestamp=(guint64)1000;
static GstClockTime dtimestamp= 0;
static GstPadProbeReturn

display_data (GstPad          *pad,
              GstBuffer *apsInfo,
              gpointer         user_data)
{
  // apsInfo = gst_buffer_ref(apsInfo);  

  // apsInfo = gst_buffer_make_writable(apsInfo);
  //   int fps = 30;

  //   ptimestamp += gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, fps);

  //   int a=GST_BUFFER_PTS (apsInfo) ;
  //   int b=GST_BUFFER_DTS (apsInfo) ;
  //   GST_BUFFER_PTS (apsInfo)=ptimestamp;
  //   GST_BUFFER_DTS (apsInfo)=ptimestamp;;
  //   //printf("%d %d \n",a,b);
  //   GST_BUFFER_DURATION (apsInfo) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, fps);
    
}
static GstPadProbeReturn
change_time (GstPad          *pad,
              GstBuffer *apsInfo,
              gpointer         user_data)
{
  //printf("change ing time");
  //apsInfo = gst_buffer_ref(apsInfo); 
  //apsInfo = gst_buffer_make_writable(apsInfo);
  /* when these commented lines are added the buffer status returns gst_buffer_is_writable
  writern wrtable but any changes in code does not effect the video but when these lines are 
  removed the buffer status writern not writable but the changes in code effect the video 
  */
        GST_BUFFER_FLAG_SET (apsInfo, GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DISCONT);
  
    int fps = 30;

   dtimestamp += gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, fps);
   ptimestamp += gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, fps);

   int a=GST_BUFFER_PTS (apsInfo) = ptimestamp;
   int b=GST_BUFFER_DTS (apsInfo) = dtimestamp;
   printf("%d %d \n",a,b);
   GST_BUFFER_DURATION (apsInfo) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (1, GST_SECOND, fps);
    
}
static void
dec_counter (GstElement * pipeline)
{
  if (prerolled)
    return;

  if (g_atomic_int_dec_and_test (&counter)) {
    /* all probes blocked and no-more-pads signaled, post
     * message on the bus. */
    prerolled = TRUE;

    gst_bus_post (bus, gst_message_new_application (
          GST_OBJECT_CAST (pipeline),
          gst_structure_new_empty ("ExPrerolled")));
  }
}

/* called when a source pad of uridecodebin is blocked */
static GstPadProbeReturn
cb_blocked (GstPad          *pad,
            GstPadProbeInfo *info,
            gpointer         user_data)
{
  GstElement *pipeline = GST_ELEMENT (user_data);

  if (prerolled)
    return GST_PAD_PROBE_REMOVE;

  dec_counter (pipeline);

  return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
}

/* called when uridecodebin has a new pad */
static void
cb_pad_added (GstElement *element,
              GstPad     *pad,
              gpointer    user_data)
{
  GstElement *pipeline = GST_ELEMENT (user_data);

  if (prerolled)
    return;

  g_atomic_int_inc (&counter);

  gst_pad_add_probe (pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM,
      (GstPadProbeCallback) cb_blocked, pipeline, NULL);

  /* try to link to the video pad */
  gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);
  

}

/* called when uridecodebin has created all pads */
static void
cb_no_more_pads (GstElement *element,
                 gpointer    user_data)
{
  GstElement *pipeline = GST_ELEMENT (user_data);

  if (prerolled)
    return;

  dec_counter (pipeline);
}

/* called when a new message is posted on the bus */
static void
cb_message (GstBus     *bus,
            GstMessage *message,
            gpointer    user_data)
{
  GstElement *pipeline = GST_ELEMENT (user_data);

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (message)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
      g_print ("we received an error!\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("we reached EOS\n");
      g_main_loop_quit (loop);
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_APPLICATION:
    {
      if (gst_message_has_name (message, "ExPrerolled")) {
        /* it's our message */
        g_print ("we are all prerolled, do seek\n");
gst_element_seek (pipeline, 1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH,
                         GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0,
                         GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);

        gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
}


gint
main (gint   argc,
      gchar *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *src, *csp, *vs, *sink ,*idelem;

  /* init GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);



  /* build */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("my-pipeline");

  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus);
  g_signal_connect (bus, "message", (GCallback) cb_message,
      pipeline);

  src = gst_element_factory_make ("uridecodebin", "src");

  if (src == NULL)
    g_error ("Could not create 'uridecodebin' element");

  g_object_set (src, "uri", "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4", NULL);

  csp = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "csp");
  if (csp == NULL)
    g_error ("Could not create 'videoconvert' element");

  vs = gst_element_factory_make ("videoscale", "vs");
  if (csp == NULL)
    g_error ("Could not create 'videoscale' element");

  idelem = gst_element_factory_make ("identity", "identity-elem");
  if (idelem == NULL)
    g_error ("Could not create 'idelem' ");

  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");
  if (sink == NULL)
    g_error ("Could not create 'autovideosink' element");

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), src, csp, vs,idelem, sink, NULL);

  /* can't link src yet, it has no pads */
  gst_element_link_many (csp, vs,idelem, sink, NULL);

  sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (csp, "sink");
  //ident_sink = gst_element_get_static_pad (idelem, "sink");

  // //  
  // gst_pad_add_probe (sinkpad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
  //     (GstPadProbeCallback) display_data, NULL, NULL); //displayinfo data
  // gst_object_unref (sinkpad);



GstElement *identity_elem = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "identity-elem");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(identity_elem), "signal-handoffs", TRUE, NULL);   //change time
g_signal_connect(idelem, "handoff",  (GCallback)  change_time, pipeline);



  g_atomic_int_set (&counter, 1);

  g_signal_connect (src, "pad-added",
      (GCallback) cb_pad_added, pipeline);
  g_signal_connect (src, "no-more-pads",
      (GCallback) cb_no_more_pads, pipeline);

  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED);

  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

  gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  g_main_loop_unref (loop);

  return 0;
}
```